# Select query by splitted string is it possible? [Split the Table Field Value as Multiple Records]

Tags: c#, ms-access, select, visual-studio-2015

I have 2 tables MyTbl1, MyTbl2 contains the followings And I wish to have a Select Query
to get the Output like the table MySplittedTbl2

```
MyCodes
Select * from MyTbl2 ??????????

MyTbl1
order_no, item_name, order_qty
A001       Paper      1000
A002       Pen        2000
A003       Pencil     2500
A004       Ink        1500

`MyTbl2
bill_no   order_no     billing_qty
001       A001         1000
002       A001,A002    1000,2000
003       A002         1500
004       A002,A003    500,2000
```

From the above MyTbl2 I wish to split order_no column by ,(comma) and duplicated as another row , is it possible?

```
MySplittedTbl2
bill_no   order_no     billing_qty
001       A001         1000
002       A001         1000
002       A002         2000
003       A002         1500
004       A002          500
004       A003         2000
```

Thank For The Gudences
Thank Regards
Paraman

Comment: Yes, create a small helper function that uses `Split` _by comma_ to take either the first or the second value of `billing_qty`. Then create one query that takes the first value and another that take the second value (if any), and, finally, create a union query that combines the two queries.

Comment: MyTbl1 seems irrelevant; unless we cannot rely on order in MyTbl2.billing_qty

Comment: These are comma-separated strings, not a multi-value field? Never more than two elements in each CSV string?

Comment: In the first table `A003       Pencil     2500` but in the 2nd `003       A002         1500` which is correct? MySplittedTbl2 shows 1500, but can you confirm?